# How to query for all events on a given day, using the SQL Server sysschedules model?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recurrence

Given this model: [sysschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx), and assuming there were several events in the DB with varying combinations of recurrence patterns: daily, daily every 3 days, weekly on Tues. every 2 weeks, monthly on the 28th, monthly on the second Tues of every 2 months, yearly on Feb 28th, etc...

With the model given, there are certain fields that immediately jump to mind:

- **freq_type** to get whether the even is daily, weekly, monthly, etc...
- **freq_interval** to determine the interval, based on the freq_type
- **freq_relative_interval** to determine if events are on 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc... of month
- **freq_recurrence_factor** to determine the weekly/monthly spacing between event occurrences

If I wanted to query for all events that are today, Tuesday 28 Feb, 2012... what would that look like?

**Update**
Here's what I've come up with so far (in this example I want all "events" that occur on Feb 28 (which is a Tues):
`SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (freq_type = 1 && active_start_date = '2012-02-28') OR (freq_type = 4) OR (freq_type = 8 && freq_interval = 4) OR (freq_type = 32 && freq_interval = 3 && freq_relative_interval = 16)`

- freq_type of 1 means it's only once, get by the active_start_date
- freq_type of 4 means daily, get all those since they'd occur on this day too
- freq_type of 8 means weekly, get those events on freq_interval 4 (Tues)
- freq_type of 32 means monthly, relative - freq_interval 3 (Tues), freq_relative_interval 16 for last

Here's what immediately jumps to mind as "*wrong*"

**1.** What about events that are weekly, but more than one day, including Tuesday? For example, a weekly event which occurs every Tues/Thurs, will have a freq_interval of 20. How would I rewrite the query above to account for all possible combinations of freq_interval which can be Tues?

**2.** What about events which occur every n weeks/months? How do I know if it's this week/month's "on or off" time-frame?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of jobs that run on particular day in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245015/how-to-get-list-of-jobs-that-run-on-particular-day-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @Tony - That question doesn't answer how to pick events scheduled for a specific date.

Comment: @Dems - You are correct, it does not, I didn't read the other question fully. Sorry, I don't seem to be able to retract the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't able to fully test. This doesn't cover every possibility. For instance, if an event happens every 3 days, some calculating will need to be done for the the dates and days, etc.

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       msdb.dbo.sysschedules 
WHERE   (active_start_date = 20120228) 
    OR (freq_type = 4 AND freq_interval = 1)  --every day
    OR (freq_type = 4 AND freq_interval = 14 AND datename(dw, convert(datetime, convert(varchar(8), active_start_date), 112)) = 'Tuesday') --every 14 days, starting on a Tuesday
        OR (freq_type = 8 AND ((freq_interval & 4) = 4))  -- every Tuesday
        OR (freq_type = 16 AND freq_interval = 28) -- every month on the 28th
        OR (freq_type = 32 AND freq_interval = 3 
            AND (freq_relative_interval = 8 OR freq_relative_interval = 16))  -- monthly on a Tuesday of the Fourth or Last week
```

Comment: Thank you, the bitwise operator was what I was looking for. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Chad: Bit masking is always fun and efficient! :) Gets you down on the register level, almost like assembler!

Answer (score 4):

The system table [sysjobschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188924.aspx) contains information about when a job ran and the date/time when it will next run. You might be able to use that to find when a job will run on a particular day.

It's not without problems; the dates are stored as integers and need converting before they are useful and the information is *updated only after the jobstep completes*. So you would only get back results for the jobs which have executed at least once.

I found this information from the **SQL Server Agent Job Execution Information** section of the page [Querying SQL Server Agent Job Information](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/)

There is also some community content on the bottom of the MSDN page giving a UDF to get a datetime from integer which you can use to decode the dates.

**UPDATE**

After thinking about your problem, and realising you are trying to replicate the `sysschedules` model and not just use it, I thought I should update my answer.

You asked :

> How would I rewrite the query above to account for all possible
>   combinations of freq_interval which can be Tues?

I creating a table with the bit mask values for the days and then joined that to the schedule table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule_Day](
    [day_name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [day_bit_value] [varbinary](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT Schedule_Day(day_name, day_bit_value) VALUES ('Sunday', 1)
INSERT Schedule_Day(day_name, day_bit_value) VALUES ('Monday', 2)
INSERT Schedule_Day(day_name, day_bit_value) VALUES ('Tuesday', 4)
INSERT Schedule_Day(day_name, day_bit_value) VALUES ('Wednesday', 8)
INSERT Schedule_Day(day_name, day_bit_value) VALUES ('Thursday', 16)
INSERT Schedule_Day(day_name, day_bit_value) VALUES ('Friday', 32)
INSERT Schedule_Day(day_name, day_bit_value) VALUES ('Saturday', 64)

SELECT Schedule.schedule_id, Schedule.start_date, Schedule_Day.day_name
FROM Schedule INNER JOIN Schedule_Day 
    ON Schedule.freq_interval & Schedule_Day.day_bit_value > 0
```

Here is the result for a schedule running on Tuesday and Thursday:

```
schedule_id freq_type freq_interval freq_recurrence_factor start_date
----------- --------- ------------- ---------------------- ----------
          1        32            20                      1 2012-03-06

schedule_id  start_date  day_name
-----------  ----------  --------
          1  2012-03-06  Tuesday   
          1  2012-03-06  Thursday
```

However, the difficult part is extrapolating the dates going forward to get all the future Tuesdays and Thursdays with month intervals. That's an exercise I'll leave to you :)

I've previously created a simplified schedule system which you might be able to use to provide a solution *almost* as good. You can simulate a schedule which executes on Tuesday & Thursday by having multiple schedule entries, grouped in some way.

My schedule design included an `active_on_day` field which indicated the day of the week when the schedule was allowed to run, so a `job` referring to more than one schedule would run on those days. I can post the table design and stored procedures if you are interested.

Comment: Hmm, so this model could not be used to build an "event calendar" type system? One that would allow recurring events and not allow changing each individual occurrence.

It looks like it would work. The intervals, frequencies, start and end dates are there. 

Would you recommend a different model? If so, which? Thanks Tony!

Comment: @Chad - Are you are thinking of using the SQL Server scheduling system tables to store schedules which will be executed by your own code? If so I wouldn't recommend it; it's easy to set up your own schedule table and use a stored procedure to poll for active jobs. I created such a system a while ago, I'll see if I can find some SQL to post.

Comment: No, was just thinking of using some of the concepts in the sysschedules table like: freq_type, interval, etc... to build an "event calendar" so my users can post "events"... as-in real-life events they can attend. I need to be able to support recurrence patterns such as 1st Tues/mo, every other week, Mon/Wed weekly, etc... Everyone kept pointing me to the sysschedules table for "inspiration". ;)

Comment: I found simple scheduling did for me, my table included the start date and then an increment (1,2,3...) and interval (second, minute, hour, day, week...). Do you really need all the complexity of relative dates and intervals? Keep it simple and get it working first. :)

Comment: I wish I didn't Tony... relative dates, yea... unfortunately, the user's would like the ability to set "events" to occur on the [1st/2nd/3rd/4th] day of the month, etc... I'll probably start by not having that as an option, build it into the tables, but not use them just yet... to get things started. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

there is a procedure called sp_get_schedule_description that will return the schedule on a readable format.
All the procedure's parameters can be found on the sysschedules table

So, for example, I created a Schedule called "My Schedule1" that has the following information:

```
Recuring
Weekly
Every 2 weeks
On tuesday
Overy 12 hours Starting at 3 AM enging at 9 PM
from 1/3/2012
```

if I run

```
select 
freq_type, 
freq_interval,  
freq_subday_type, 
freq_subday_interval, 
freq_relative_interval,  
freq_recurrence_factor, 
active_start_date, 
active_end_date,  
active_start_time, 
active_end_time
from sysschedules where name='My Schedule1'
```

that will give me

```
freq_type                     8
freq_interval                 5
freq_subday_type              8
freq_subday_interval          12
freq_relative_interval        0
freq_recurrence_factor        2
active_start_date             20120301          
active_end_date               99991231        
active_start_time             30000             
active_end_time               210000
```

if I put these values into sp_get_schedule_description  like this:

```
declare @schedule_description NVARCHAR(255)
exec sp_get_schedule_description 8, 5, 8, 12, 0, 2, 20120301, 99991231, 30000, 210000, @schedule_description output
select @schedule_description
```

Ill get the schedule on a readable format:

```
Every 2 week(s) on Sunday, Tuesday every 12 hour(s) between 30000 and 210000
```

problem is that it take one schedule at a time, so you would need to come up with some sort of loop to call it once per job putting the description in a temp table ofr example and the you query the temp table with your parameters
like on 1:

```
select * 
from your_table 
where description like '%Tuesday%'
```